# TextView not displaying while in a FrameLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-framelayout

I wrote a custom GroupView class which displays it's children in a X by Y grid. The children are squares.

```
package com.roundel.calc2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CalcPadLayout extends ViewGroup {
private int mRowCount;
private int mColumnCount;
public CalcPadLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            new int[] { android.R.attr.rowCount, android.R.attr.columnCount }, defStyle, 0);
    mRowCount = a.getInt(0, 1);
    mColumnCount = a.getInt(1, 1);
    a.recycle();
}

public CalcPadLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CalcPadLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    final int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    final int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
    final int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
    final int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final int height = bottom-top-paddingBottom-paddingTop;
    final int width = right-left-paddingLeft-paddingRight;
    final int childSize = Math.min(Math.round(width/mColumnCount), Math.round(height/mRowCount));

    /*DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;*/
    int rowIndex = 0, columnIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        final int childTop = rowIndex*childSize+paddingTop;
        final int childLeft = columnIndex*childSize+paddingLeft;
        final int childBottom = childTop+childSize;
        final int childRight = childLeft+childSize;
        //child.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childRight, childBottom);
        rowIndex = (rowIndex + (columnIndex + 1) / mColumnCount) % mRowCount;
        columnIndex = (columnIndex + 1) % mColumnCount;
    }
    LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = childSize*mRowCount+paddingTop+paddingBottom;
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
}
}
```

This is my main_layout.xml. Lets display two TextViews inside two FrameLayouts, I'll set a background color of the FrameLayouts so I can see if they are displaying properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <com.roundel.calc2.CalcPadLayout
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:background="@color/greyDark"
        android:gravity="bottom">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="35sp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="35sp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </com.roundel.calc2.CalcPadLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layouts are displaying properly, however the TextView is invisible
[image: Inside FrameLayouts]
When I remove the FrameLayout it works, however for no reason the text is only centered verticaly and not horizontaly.
[image: Outside the FrameLayouts]

Comment: I'm sorry for those huge images, no idea how to make them smaller

Answer (score 0):

If that is your final Layout, you do not need the FrameLayout.
You can set the background color directly in the textView.
Try to use as less layout levels as possible.

Also for the text alignment it is because your textView stub has a "Wrap_content" value.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <com.roundel.calc2.CalcPadLayout
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:background="@color/greyDark"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="35sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp"/>
    </com.roundel.calc2.CalcPadLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need to use a Layout, because later on I'm animating It's translationZ to make it appear as if it was "rising from a surface"

Comment: Anyway, even if i don't use a layout the text isn't centered, that's another problem